# Oracle sqlplus functions shows as ###

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

After submitting a select query, which contains functions such as row_number() or any other function the result is ####. If I use rownum as something, it shows ### if I use just rownum everything is ok.

I had this problem with other generic columns but I could simply use column columnname format 9999;

The problem is not that there is not enough space, there is only one digit per record.

I have googled all over the internet and nothing has answered my problem yet.

Does anyone know what could be the problem with functions and how to format them?

[image: Query and result here]

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY student_surname) "Nr.", 
      student_surname || ' ' || student_name "Student", 
      NVL(sum(m.stipend),0) + NVL(sum(m.compensation),0) "Total" 
from student s 
  inner join money m on m.student_id=s.id_student 
group by student_surname, student_name;
```

Have tried clear columns, did not work.

Comment: Provide us with the query you are using and with the ouput please

Comment: Added query and result

Comment: Just for testing, replace "Nr." with NR and execute ```COLUMN NR FORMAT A50```. That will make that first column 50 char wide. Then run the statement (with NR not "Nr.")

Comment: In general, sqlplus isn't the most modern (first used in 1884...) option to run queries. I'd consider sql developer or - if you are into command line clients - sqlcl. The problem you're seeing here has to do with sqlplus column formatting - I'm almost sure of that.

Comment: Khm, "first used in **1884**"@Koen? :)

Comment: @Littlefoot wanted to make it extra old ;). Its 1984 obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you formatted numeric column with a wrong format, which doesn't allow all digits to be displayed.

For example, this is someone's salary - looks OK:

```
SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;

       SAL
----------
       920
```

But, if you formatted it as follows (i.e. saying that I want to have only two digits (`99`) for that column), the result is `###`:

```
SQL> col sal format 99
SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;

SAL
---
###

SQL>
```

What to do? The simplest way is to `clear` formatting:

```
SQL> col sal clear
SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;

       SAL
----------
       920

SQL>
```

---

Another possibility is that `numformat` (in general) is wrongly set; all these columns are `NUMBER`, and all of them are affected with this `set numformat`:

```
SQL> set numformat 9
SQL> select empno, mgr, sal, deptno from emp where rownum = 1;

     EMPNO        MGR        SAL     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
########## ########## ########## ##########
```

How to fix that? Exit SQL*Plus and reconnect.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer and yes, the true answer was just restarting. Funnily enough, I think I did that, but because of your answer did restart it again. And now everything works. Thank you again, been struggling with this for hours.